# Sharing auto renewed certificate to multiple Azure Key Vaults

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

We have two Azure subscriptions, one for development and one for production.
Our development subscription has multiple resource groups with our product duplicated to each one (For development testing of multiple changes at the same time).
Our production subscription also has a fail over instance running in a separate resource group and data center.
As part of our solution we have App Services, Key Vault and Cloud Service Extended.

The Cloud Service Extended requires the Key Vault to be in the same Resource group as itself to load the keys, (at least this is my understanding).

For our Rest API which is implemented by the Cloud Service we are sharing the same wild card SSL certificate to all of our Cloud Services, this is a certificate from Global Sign.

It is currently my understanding if we setup the Auto Renew feature within Azure Key Vault we will be charged for a new certificate for every Key Vault instance.

Is that correct?

Assuming it is then I assume if I want to avoid that cost I would have to manage this differently.
What is the best practice here?
What are other people doing to solve this?

Searching I have found it would be possible to extract a PFX certificate from one Key Vault and upload it to another Key Vault.
Is anyone doing this to solve the above?
How do you trigger this process to run?
Is there another Azure product (Logic App for example) that could be used to do this for me?

Changing to DigiCert is an option if the integration with that CA would be better.